# how to get the user's timeline of one's own twitter account through twitter api in java

Tags: twitter

I had been trying to get my timeline messages through some Java code explained in the http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/114/entry-4459-demo-of-twitter-application-only-oauth-authentication-using-java blog and wrote some code in Java.

I am using application-only authentication and using consumer key and consumer secret. Here is a portion of my code where I am requesting the bearer token:

> bearerToken=requestBearerToken("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/besra_u_timeline.json");

Is this the right way? I ask because in the requestBearerToken method

```
private static String requestBearerToken(String endPointUrl) throws IOException {

            HttpsURLConnection connection = null;                                                          

            URL url = new URL(endPointUrl);

            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
            try {
                 connection.getInputStream();

            } catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("IOException");
            }
```

I am constantly getting an IOException which means that I am not getting the input stream from the connection object. Please help me to get the tweets.

Answer (score 0):

Ya i have got a way to do it using the twitter4j api.Consumer key , consumer secret, access token and access secret u can get once u register ur app in dev.twitter.com/apps

```
import twitter4j.ResponseList;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class SimpleCrawler {

    static ResponseList<Status> statuses;                      
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {               
        ConfigurationBuilder cb=new ConfigurationBuilder();                              
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                .setOAuthConsumerKey("your consumer key")
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret("your con secret")
                .setOAuthAccessToken("your access token")
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("access token secret");
        TwitterFactory tf=new TwitterFactory(cb.build());        
        Twitter tw = tf.getInstance();                
        try {
            statuses=tw.getHomeTimeline();
            System.out.println("Connected to twitter");
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot connect to Twitter");
            System.exit(0);
        }              
        System.out.println("Reading TimeLine...");                       
        for(Status st1:statuses){                                                
           String data[]={st1.getUser().getName(),String.valueOf(st1.getCreatedAt()),twtmsg};                 
           System.out.println(data);
         }                                               
    }

}
```

Through twitter api also its possible but don't know . One problem with this method is that it fetches 20 tweets only at a time ,any help would be appreciated.suggestions are most welcome plz comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Paging:

```
 Paging paging = new Paging();
 paging.setPage(1);
 ResponseList<Status> statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline(paging);
 System.out.println(statuses.size());
 paging.setPage(2);
 statuses.addAll(twitter.getHomeTimeline(paging));
 System.out.println(statuses.size());
```

The above simplified code will give you two pages worth of `statuses`